# Field formatter conditions problem

Tags: entities

I'm using the [Field Formatter Condition module](https://www.drupal.org/project/ffc). I have two fields: [Countdown Timer Field](https://www.drupal.org/project/field_countdown) and text field. I've created condition for text field: **Hide when target field is not empty** and target field is the countdown timer field.

Everything is working fine, but when Countdown hits 00:00:00, it takes over a dozen of seconds for condition to work and hide the countdown and show the text field.

Is there a solution to run this condition immediately after countdown hits 00:00:00?